# Jquery show/hide why it's not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got div that I want to show after hover another  element. They are not in the same div. popup info should show when an icon with class `.option_36_124` is hovered

```js
$(".option_36_124").hover(function() {
  $('.poupinfo').show();
}, function() {
  $('.poupinfo').hide();
});
```

```css
.poupinfo {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 250px;
  right: 527px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="product_info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle option_36_124"></i></span>
```

Comment: share your complete HTML

Comment: If you remove display: none does it show where you are expecting it to?

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal you can check the whole site here https://mukko.pl/pl/p/Plakat-NEVER-MIND/51

Comment: @Coffeebean yes

Comment: your class name is different product_info please check css

Comment: When I run your code in my developer console it is working fine. Where are you including your jQuery?

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal so should i just copy/paste whole html code?

Comment: @Coffeebean jquery is included in header - and its working fine becouse I'm using it on site already.

Comment: @DamianWicik Maybe until someone else can access it and tell you what exactly the problem is

Comment: @Coffeebean ok..that's weird. Im injecting this jquery code together with script that is injecting photos that are loaded in...

Comment: What is the name of the file that contains your code?

Comment: I also can't find .popupinfo in the DOM (although if you're dynamically building that element and the whole script is missing that would explain this too).

Comment: @Coffeebean skins/user/rwd_shoper_5/cache/sfc/MTY6MTowOnBsX1BMOjA6MTptYWluLWpxOjIyOjUuOC4xNg.js it's all based on SHOPER - ready to work shop cms so that's why it's so "complicated"

Comment: @delinear it should be .poupinfo - my bad sorry.

Comment: Well it works for me. See https://jsfiddle.net/dags77eb/.

Comment: @Coffeebean Ty for help ;) i just answered my own question

Answer (score 2):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".option_36_124").hover(function(){
    $('.poupinfo').show();
},function(){
    $('.poupinfo').hide();
});
});
```

Got the answer here.

Comment: Well done for answering your own question :) now explain why it worked!

Comment: Probably this whole JS is loaded all before the page - so i needed to wait for page to load, and then inject script. I think it is working like that - but to be true i'm not sure...

Comment: I agree. It was running before the class existed

Comment: Check my answer below, you don't have to use `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

your HTML structure needed a bit of rework (so that the icon and the content are not parent-child related but siblings, making the icon always visible and not reliant on the content) and also you targeted your .show() and .hide() to an erroneous (non-existing) class. Hope this helps:

```js
$(".option_36_124").hover(function(){
    $('.product_info').show();
},function(){
    $('.product_info').hide();
});
```

```css
 .product_info{
    background: black;
    color: white;
    top: 150px;
    right: 527px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-info-circle option_36_124">icon (hover me)</i>
<span class="product_info">content</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working check code below

```js
$(".option_36_124").hover(function() {
  $('.poupinfo').show();
}, function() {
  $('.poupinfo').hide();
});
```

```css
.poupinfo {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 250px;
  right: 527px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  top:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="product_info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle option_36_124"></i></span>

<div class="poupinfo">Hii! i am visible now </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of `jQuery` or any script, for me I prefer to use `:pseudo` elements, a combination of `:hover` and `:after` could give you the result you want, and the great thing that you didn't use any script!

Pure CSS3 just :)

```css
   .fa-info-circle:hover::after {
      content: 'hey im popup info!';
      background: black;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 250px;
      left: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="product_info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle option_36_124"></i></span>
```